# Can we make a listview behave like expandablelistview

Tags: android

Can we make an `ListView` behave like an `ExpandableListView`? I have an header with a button, with `ListView` below it. On the click of the Header Button can i `expand/collapse?`

[image]

Comment: what do you want to show below the clicked item?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu: I have a header a group of lists... i would like the lists to be expandaded and collapsed on the click of header button image...

Comment: this is a really good scenario for `ExpandableListView`. Why not use it?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu: i have multiple list views in my activity.

Comment: that's a bad design. you need to have an expandable list view.

Comment: yeah... maybe you should `setVisibility(View.GONE)` when the user click on header... to hide the list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28450/discussion-between-kevin-and-ovidiu-latcu)

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu: In that case, am i using the listView correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Slide Expandable ListView](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/slide-expandable-listview/) is an awesome open source view that could work for you.